# Why my packaged eel app failed to execute : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, attributeerror, nonetype, eel

I keep getting this error when trying to execute my app.exe ( generated with
python -m eel [your_main_script] [your_web_folder] --onefile --noconsole)

My code is too long to post here.

Here is the full unhandled exception thrown where tempting to execute the app

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "survey.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "eel\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "bottle.py", line 73, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

My libraries have been updated and I checked that I'm writing in files with valid paths

Answer (score 2):

I overwrote the bottle.py files located in my python installation directory with this content https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py and it worked for me

Comment: works for me too; I overwrote bottle.py inside Scripts\ and Lib\site-packages\ folders

Comment: This also helped me! On two separate occasions (different projects on different PCs and Python versions).

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me, seems to be a problem with sys.stdout when using --windowed pyinstaller (with no console to output to) so stdout == None.

https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/commit/5e2efb6ad9c12d986c59926d0b3f99be003189d0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. In my case I had tqdm library which writes to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem!

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\bottle.py -> Comment out this code!:

Line 73:

try:
_stdout, _stderr = sys.stdout.write, sys.stderr.write
except IOError:
_stdout = lambda x: sys.stdout.write(x)
_stderr = lambda x: sys.stderr.write(x)